# Small doubts about how the Spinner widget works in Kivy / Python

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I need help with the Spinner widget. My first question is how do I change the size of the buttons in the spinner drop-down list, because my active button the spinner is small, but my drop-down list is text, so it needs to be wide enough to read the text (I'll exemplify the problem by the photo). The second problem is that I don't want the text in the spinner's drop-down list to fill in the button (I'll exemplify in a photo). And the third problem is that I want that inside the spinner I can call a function that is inside the class application, defining one of the values ​​in the drop-down list (I will exemplify in photos).

main.kv

```
...
Spinner:
    size_hint: None, None
    width: '30sp'
    height: '30sp'
    border: 0,0,0,0
    background_normal: 'imag1.png'
    background_down: 'imag2.png'
    values: "gelo","carvão","salmão"
    on_text: 'gelo'                           
        on_release: app.IluminanciaMaceió()  #I know it's wrong, but I want the action to be this, how could I fix it?
...
```

main.py

```
...
class MainApp(App):
    texture = ObjectProperty()
    
    def iluminanciamaceio(self):
        mac = 21000
        mac = str(21000)
        self.root.get_screen('primeira').ids.ie.text = mac
        self.root.get_screen('primeira').ids.nlocaliza.text = 'Maceió'

...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Spinner` has no option to allow the `DropDown` to be a different width than the `Spinner` itself. You can define your own extension of `Spinner` that has that ability.

To call a method when a `Button` in the `Spinner` `DropDown` is clicked, just use the `on_text` event of the `Spinner`:

```
    on_text: app.some_method(self.text)
```

Then, in that method, you can decide what to do based on the text:

```
def some_method(self, button_text):
    print('Button text:', button_text)
```

Comment: could you show me the correct way to create this spinner class and add the features i need? I added part of the code that I need to fix on this link here on the site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67295056/how-do-i-increase-the-width-of-the-dropdown-list-within-a-spinner